# Passing IMars interface as parameter to method using Unity MARS plugin

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to implement body tracking using Unity's MARS plugin using API given by mars plugin called `IProvidesMarsBodyTracking`. Below is script that inherits interface and Monobehaviour.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using Unity.MARS.Providers;
using System;
using Unity.MARS.Data;

public class BodyTrackManager : MonoBehaviour, IProvidesMarsBodyTracking
{
    public event Action<IMarsBody> BodyAdded;
    public event Action<IMarsBody> BodyUpdated;
    public event Action<IMarsBody> BodyRemoved;

    [SerializeField] GameObject marsBody;

    public void ConnectSubscriber(object obj)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public void GetBodies(List<IMarsBody> bodies)
    {
        BodyAdded += BodyTrackManager_BodyAdded;
        Debug.Log("Test");
    }

    private void BodyTrackManager_BodyAdded(IMarsBody obj)
    {
        marsBody.transform.position = obj.BodyPose.bodyPosition;
        marsBody.SetActive(true);
    }

    public void LoadProvider()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public void UnloadProvider()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

This script is attached MARS camera and I have taken a sphere object as reference tracker just observe weather the body is tracked and untracked. `BodyTrackManager_BodyAdded` is custom method which is registered on `BodyAdded` event. Here I'm not able to understand which object should be passed as parameter to `BodyTrackManager_BodyAdded`, as it accepts `IMars` as interface.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a class that implements IMarsBody so that it can supply the data to subscribers. Rather than subscribing to the BodyAdded event, you are meant to *invoke* that event when a body is tracked.

Are you sure you want `IProvidesMarsBodyTracking` and not `IUsesMarsBodyTracking`? The provider side is meant to be implemented by AR data providers like ARKit or ARCore. For example, a body tracking provider might be hooked up to a machine learning model that tracks human bodies in a video feed, and then implements this interface to provide data about these tracked bodies to the system. `IUsesMarsBodyTracking`, on the other end, is intended to be implemented by game code to get *access* to that data.

Comment: Hi @Matt Schoen Thanks for the help. I figured it out, I need to use IUsesMarsBodyTracking and not IProvidesMarsBodyTracking, now I am successfull in subscribing Body tracking events but now the issue is How to unsubscribe, like where to call .SubscribeBodyRemoved(OnBodyRemoved); in Unity life cycle methods.

Comment: I think I was able to answer this over on the Unity forum. :)  For those who are curious, there is an `UnsubscribeBodyAdded` to unsubscribe from the event.